# How to define maps in template file for terraform to pick it up

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

My code is as follows, so the custom_parameter fails to be decoded, I'm not sure how I can define this maps in template file, How can I define the maps variable in template file.

Invalid template interpolation value; Cannot include the given value in a
│ string template: string required..

main.tf looks like this

```
resource "google_dataflow_flex_template_job" "dataflow_jobs_static" {
  provider = google-beta
  for_each = {
    for k, v in var.dataflows : k => v
    if v.type == "static"
  }
  parameters = merge(
    yamldecode(templatefile("df/${each.key}/config.yaml", {
      tf_host_project         = var.host_project
      tf_dataflow_subnet      = var.dataflow_subnet
      tf_airflow_project      = local.airflow_project
      tf_common_project       = "np-common"
      tf_dataeng_project      = local.dataeng_project
      tf_domain               = var.domain
      tf_use_case             = var.use_case
      tf_env                  = var.env
      tf_region               = lookup(local.regions, each.value.region, "northamerica-northeast1")
      tf_short_region         = each.value.region
      tf_dataflow_job         = each.key
      tf_dataflow_job_img_tag = each.value.active_img_tag
      tf_metadata_json        = indent(6, file("df/${each.key}/metadata.json"))
      tf_sdk_language         = each.value.sdk_language
      tf_custom_parameters    = each.value.custom_parameters[*]
    }))
  )
 
}
```

terraform.tfvars looks like this

```
dataflows                         = {
  "lastflow"                        = {
    type                              = "static"                                     
    region                            = "nane1"
    sdk_language                      = "JAVA"
    active_img_tag                    = "0.2"                                        
    custom_parameters = {
       bootstrapServers = "abc,gv"
    }                  
  },
```

vars.tf

```
variable "dataflows" {
  type = map(object({
    type           = string
    region         = string
    sdk_language   = string
    active_img_tag = string
    custom_parameters  = map(string)
  }))


  default = {}
}
```

config.yaml

```
custom_var: ${tf_custom_parameters}
```

Also my metadata json file looks like this

```
{
  "name": "Streaming Beam PubSub to Kafka Testing",
  "description": "An Apache Beam streaming pipeline that reads JSON encoded messages from Pub/Sub, uses Beam to transform the message data, and writes the results to a Kafka",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "custom_var",
      "isOptional": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Error

```
Error: Error in function call
│ 
│   on dataflow.tf line 60, in resource "google_dataflow_flex_template_job" "dataflow_jobs_static":

│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.key is "lastflow"
│     │ each.value.active_img_tag is "0.2"
│     │ each.value.custom_parameters is map of string with 1 element
│     │ each.value.region is "nane1"
│     │ each.value.sdk_language is "JAVA"
│     │ local.airflow_project is "-01"
│     │ local.dataeng_project is "-02"
│     │ local.regions is object with 2 attributes
│     │ var.common_project_index is "01"
│     │ var.dataflow_subnet is "dev-01"
│     │ var.domain is "datapltf"
│     │ var.env is "npe"
│     │ var.host_project is "rod-01"
│     │ var.use_case is "featcusto"
│ 
│ Call to function "templatefile" failed: df/lastflow/config.yaml:2,15-35:
│ Invalid template interpolation value; Cannot include the given value in a
│ string template: string required..
```

Comment: All else being equal, the error message states the expectation that the `tf_custom_parameters` value should be a String, and it is definitely not a String type as invoked by `templatefile`.

Comment: Yes, I understand. And Im stuck on how to define that variable it in config.yaml file

Comment: You are not defining it there; you are referencing it. The error is with your value assignment in the second argument to the `templatefile` function.

Comment: I should remove it from template file?

Comment: Then it would be `null` and fail for a different reason during resolution. You need to fix the value to be a String type as a first step.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I fixed this by referencing to the foll. doc
https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile#maps
following that, my solution is as follows,
the config.yaml was changed to be like this

```
%{ for key, value in tf_custom_parameters }
${key}: ${value}
%{ endfor ~}
```

And the metadata.json file changed to be as follows

```
{
  "name": "Streaming Beam PubSub to Kafka Testing",
  "description": "An Apache Beam streaming pipeline that reads JSON encoded messages from Pub/Sub, uses Beam to transform the message data, and writes the results to a Kafka",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "bootstrapServers",
      "label": "test label.",
      "isOptional": true,
      "helpText": "test help Text"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the one change in main.tf file was this

```
.........
.........
     tf_custom_parameters    = each.value.custom_parameters
.........
```

this the solution that helped.